# How to fetch Dependent field options under using Restlet?

Tags: javascript, php, netsuite

I created following dependent fields in CRM,

parentitem & childitem

parentitem is controlling field

childitem is dependent field

In parentitem field going to select Food option

[image: parentitem field option selection]

In childitem field shown Food items depend on parentitem selection

[image: childitem field option selection]

Here is my sample Restlet code for Retrieve Fields & options from netsuite crm.

```
function getFields(datain) {
    var record = nlapiCreateRecord(datain.recordtype);
    var fields = record.getAllFields();
    var requiredFields = {};
    fields.forEach(function(fieldName) {
            var field = record.getField(fieldName);
            if (field.mandatory === true && field.disabled === false) {
                    var id = field.getName();
                    var field_details = {}
                    field_details['DefaultValue'] = record.getFieldValue(fieldName);
                    field_details['DefaultText'] = record.getFieldText(fieldName);
                    field_details['Type'] = field.getType();
                    field_details['Label'] = field.getLabel();
                    if (field.getType() == 'select' || field.getType() == 'multiselect') {
                            var Options = field.getSelectOptions();
                            var selectOptions = {}
                            for (var i in Options) {
                                    var opt_id = Options[i].getId();
                                    selectOptions[opt_id] = Options[i].getText()
                            }
                            field_details['Options'] = selectOptions;
                    }
                    requiredFields[id] = field_details;
            }
    });
    return requiredFields;
}
```

Using above code i can get parentitem field & options.

```
[custevent37] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [DefaultValue] => 
                [DefaultText] => 
                [Type] => select
                [Label] => parentitem
                [Options] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Food
                        [2] => Electronics
                    )

            )

    )
```

But i can't get childitem(dependent on parentitem) field options it only shown empty options array. Actually childitem field has options in CRM. but it only shown after parentitem selection

```
 [custevent38] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [DefaultValue] => 
                [DefaultText] => 
                [Type] => select
                [Label] => childitem
                [Options] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )
```

Any idea how to get Dependent field options using Restlet?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Sample code to get dependent fields options using Restlet,

'**parentfieldid**' -> parent field id.

'**2**' -> internal id of the parent field value.

'**childfieldid**' is the dependent field for '**parentfieldid**'

```
myRec.setFieldValue('parentfieldid','2'); //set values for parentfield
var myFld = myRec.getField('childfieldid'); // get dependent field
var options = myFld.getSelectOptions(); // Here we can get options for childfield based on the parentfield option
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select each option on dynamic mode so you can retrieve the values on the child fields. You would need to find a way to identify the parent fields.

Alternatively you could run a search to get the internal ids and text of the child field values.